# Rails 3 - Display all message errors for a given method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if there is a way (a plugin?) to display all message errors for a given object in rails 3. For example, here my validations:

```
validates_presence_of :email, :message => "Your Email can't be blank"
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
```

which will be displayed in the view like this:

```
Your Email can't be blank
Email is invalid
```

If I use error_message_on (@user, :email) I'll get the first message error, So
my start has to create a loop and extract the related method (example the @user.email) Is it the right way?

## EDIT

This almost achieves it:

```
<ul>
  <%= @user.errors.on(:email).each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But it returns also the array, How can I manage this?

```
Your Email can't be blank
is invalid
["Your Email can't be blank", "is invalid"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: actually parsing `errors` for an object is a good way. You can write some small helpers for it and it will be enogh

Comment: So I will continue on this :) Thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand what you were trying to do; I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <% @user.errors.on(:email).each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and as an helper:

```
def display_all_error_messages(object, method)
  list_items = object.errors[method].map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }
  content_tag(:ul, list_items.join.html_safe)
end
```